# want mongodb find operation to return specific field,but return the document without this field

Tags: mongodb

code below

```
db.xxx.find(null,{name:1})
```

i want return all names from the collection,but the result contains the docs which don't have field 'name',like below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b6574e55b3a4bd6cf89c62"), "name" : "xxx" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b657ab55b3a4bd6cf89c63") }
```

how to remove these ones.

---

```
db.xxx.find({name:{$exists:true}},{name:1});
```

can work , but i think this solution is ugly.Are there better solutions?

---

the comment from @JohnnyHK is useful:" query parameter determines which docs are included and the projection parameter determines what's included from each doc"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what aspect of your solution you find ugly, but you can use `distinct` if you just want the distinct set of `name` values from your docs:

```
db.xxx.distinct('name')
```

Comment: to be simple:i want the all names,if the doc does not contains 'name' field,why is the doc in the result list? can i make some config to change this behaviour?

Comment: @zilong That's simply the way MongoDB queries work.  The query parameter determines which docs are included and the projection parameter determines what's included from each doc.